# Set default link target for articles

Tags: linking

I manage a WordPress site (will be updating to 6.3.1 shortly) on Windows Server 2019, while someone else writes articles on the site domain. The WordPress site is a subdomain of the primary site, and is displayed in an iframe on the primary site.

I cannot rely on the one writing the articles to enter links with a target.

In theory, if I edit the Theme Header, I could just force ALL links on the entire site to have target of _blank with a base tag:

```
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
    <base target="_blank">
</head>
```

Ideally, though, I'd rather it only change the targets for links that don't match the subdomain so that articles linking to other articles don't create a mess of extra tabs for users.

My question is, is there is a way to dynamically set the target of certain links within all articles to _blank?

For example:

- Linking to https news.example.tld would retain the default _self target
- Linking to https example.tld would change to _blank as its link target.
- Linking to http(s) anything.else.tld would change to _blank as its link target.